# When json_string() allocated memory is freed?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, jansson

This is a stack trace of calling json_string() :

1. json_string(const char *value)
2. json_stringn(value, strlen(value))
3. json_stringn_nocheck(value, len)
4. string_create(value, len, 0)

`string_create` then call json_strndup(value,len) to duplicate value of string.

**The problem is there that I couldn't find out when this allocated memory for `value` is freed.**

Comment: You should look for reference counting in the jansson documentation. `json_decref` is your friend.

Comment: Your right. Also I had used `json_array_append_new` to add a string to an array. Dose `json_array_append_new` decrease reference of it value?

Comment: Its look `json_array_append_new` doesn't decrease the reference count, and do `reference stealing`.

Comment: Yes, it "steals" the reference. But otherwise it would **in**crease the reference.

Comment: If you don't want the reference stealing, use the version without suffix `_new`.

Comment: "However, some functions steal the reference, i.e. they have the same result as if the user called json_decref() on the argument right after calling the function."
https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.10/apiref.html#reference-count